# Android vim keyboard associated with Android clipboard (for editing text with vim commands)

Tags: android, text-editor, accessibility, clipboard, vim

The vim text editor which runs on Linux and Windows and also under several versions such as viPlugin in several IDEs and as DroidVim under Android is great.

However, it would be nice if in Android I could select text, and copy it directly to a Vim clipboard, from a web text edit, or order text editing area, and edit the selected text using commands such as cw or qq to manipulate all the text and then replace it in the text area in place. A special widget associated with the Android clipboard would have to be installed for this, and the Android Gboard keyboard overridden by a special floating vim keyboard, that was also useful (and, that could be used on Android smartphones).

Does this exist?

Thank you